# Bootstrap's JavaScript dropdown menu - Data attribute behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap's site tell us,

> Via data attributes or JavaScript, the dropdown plugin toggles hidden content (dropdown menus) by toggling the .open class on the parent list item.

In the following code, which is considered to be "via JavaScript" there is the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.myDropdownHandle').dropdown('toggle');
});
```

I was under the impression that this block of code will be necessary for the dropdown to work if we wanted to toggle "via Javascript" but I can erase that block and the dropdown will still work via the data attributes, but if I erase the data attributes the dropdown won't work at all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.myDropdownHandle').dropdown('toggle');
});
</script>  
</head>
  <body style='margin:30px'>
    <div class="dropdown" id="myDropdown">
         <a class="myDropdownHandle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="#">
            Dropdown <span  class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a  href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a  href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what exactly is your question? As you have referenced, you can init the dropdown via js call or data attributes. Please clearify your code examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This jQuery code will make it so that upon the loading of the page, your dropdown list would be showing, as in, the contents of the drop down list will be visible.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.myDropdownHandle').dropdown('toggle');
});
```

Therefore, if you don't want the dropdown toggled on page load, then remove this piece of code. However if you remove the data attribute, your dropdown will not behave as one.

Reference this [W3School Link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_dropdown.asp) will further clarify for you. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_toggle&stacked=h) is an example which shows the dropdown toggle in action.

Comment: So we never need to directly javascript to trigger the dropdown when using bootstrap? This has been helpful. I was under the impression that that piece of code was meant to trigger the dropdown when the anchor was clicked.

Comment: Correct, unless you had some other element with which you would want to trigger the opening or closing of the drop down, you can disregard this code. I am assuming this code is just an example which reveals to you how one would go about manually opening and closing the dropdown using the bootstrap api.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the bottom of the section [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-usage)

> Regardless of whether you call your dropdown via JavaScript or instead use the data-api, data-toggle="dropdown" is always required to be present on the dropdown's trigger element.

Answer (score 0):

All this line does, it decide whether you want to automatically open the menu.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.dropdown-menu').dropdown('toggle');

<div class="dropdown">
    <button id="dLabel" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown trigger
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <ul>
```

Comment: @Diego Burela  Govind and I both answered your question doing our own work.  Please upvote both, so other people will have their questions answered